# No credentials in security package when requesting a Kerberos ticket while impersonating another user

Tags: c#, kerberos, impersonation, sspi, kerberos-delegation

**Context:** Custom reverse proxy/API Gateway built in C# on top of IIS and IIS Rewrite-rules, making use of OWIN middleware.

**Goal:** I'd like the proxy to authenticate the incoming request first(this is easily configured in IIS). Having the identity available, an OWIN middleware should assert some things based on the authenticated user. Afterwards, however, the request should be sent to the backend API, *which is also windows authenticated*.

**My attempted solution:** Before sending the request further, the OWIN middleware should impersonate the authenticated identity, request a Kerberos ticket and put it to the Authorization header (as `Negotiate XXXXX.....`).

Here's the code using C# standard libs:

```
var identity = (WindowsIdentity) context.Request.User.Identity;
using (var impersonation = identity.Impersonate())
{
    var spn = "HTTP/" + backendHostname; // e.g. HTTP/myapi.mydomain.com
    var tokenProvider = new KerberosSecurityTokenProvider(spn, TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation);
    var token = tokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)) as KerberosRequestorSecurityToken;
    var ticketBytes = token.GetRequest();
    var ticket = Convert.ToBase64String(ticketBytes);
    context.Request.Headers.Append("Negotiate", ticket);
}
```

Here's an alternative implementation I tried, using [NSSPI](https://github.com/antiduh/nsspi):

```
var identity = (WindowsIdentity) context.Request.User.Identity;
using (var impersonation = identity.Impersonate())
{
    var clientCredentials = new ClientCurrentCredential(PackageNames.Kerberos);
    var client = new ClientContext(
        clientCredentials,
        "HTTP/" + backendHostname, // e.g. HTTP/myapi.mydomain.com
        ContextAttrib.MutualAuth |
        ContextAttrib.InitIdentify |
        ContextAttrib.Confidentiality |
        ContextAttrib.ReplayDetect |
        ContextAttrib.SequenceDetect |
        ContextAttrib.Connection |
        ContextAttrib.Delegate
    );
    var clientStatus = client.Init(null, out var tokenBytes);
    var token = Convert.ToBase64String(tokenBytes);
    context.Request.Headers.Append("Negotiate", token);
}
```

*Both implementations throw an exception, which boils down to the following Win32 error:*

> No credentials are available in the security package

**Important info:**

- the proxy is hosted in IIS, running under a service account (let's say `srv_ApiGateway`
- `useAppPoolCredentials` in IIS is set to `True` (otherwise IIS wouldn't be able to even authenticate the initial request using Kerberos)
- the service account (`srv_ApiGateway`) is set up for delegation in AD to `Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)`
- In both implementations, removing the impersonation and simply requesting a ticket as the service account works (just FYI)
- Both the proxy and the backend API have proper SPNs (direct requests are authenticated correctly using Kerberos).
- `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().ImpersonationLevel` inside the `using` returns `ImpersonationLevel.Impersonation` (this should proabably be `Delegation`)

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be causing this and how can I fix this double-hop reverse-proxy use-case? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I don't remember the specific anymore, but we did switch to Constrained Delegation where you have to explicitly declare which SPNs is the user allowed to delegate to instead of "any service". Not sure if that was the solution to this specific case, but maybe give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the impersonation level was not set to `Delegation` is due to invalid ticket. For some reason, Google Chrome would not request a delegation ticket for the user even though the domain is whitelisted (as per [these docs](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist)). Trying with IE and then using Chrome worked, even though not really a solution.